# How to get rid or alter default axis labels and/or titles in density plot?

Tags: r, label, subtitle

I would like to know, how can I alter "default" x label (or subtitle) in density plot in R.
For example, I do not wand this text "N = ..., bandwidth = ..." to be on the plot (I do not know if it is x-label or subtitle, but it usually appears under x-axis).

Comment: Which function do you use to produce the plot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should just use the standard plotting arguments to change the labels:

```
plot(density(rnorm(10)), 
     xlab="X", #Change the x-axis label
     ylab="Density", #y-axis label
     main="A nice title")#Main title
```

See the plotting help page: `?plot` and the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#High_002dlevel-plotting-commands).

Comment: Yes, it works. I was trying with xlab = NULL, but it turned out that in this case plot() function used default labeling. With xlab = "" the label disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

To get rib of them, simply specify them as NA

```
plot(density(rnorm(10)), 
xlab=NA, #Change the x-axis label
ylab=NA, #y-axis label
main=NA) #Main title
```

Answer (score -2):

in plot function
put **ann=FALSE**
or in separate par function

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a little bit? In it's current state, it's a little vague. Maybe put down example of how to apply it.

Comment: I am sorry for not getting back, as my account was inactive. Here it goes            in plot function,include an argument ann=FALSE ,                                                     or use                                                                                                 par(ann=FALSE) separatly

Comment: Please edit your clarifications in the answer you gave